# [leetcode 5 ]Can't really find what's wrong in my solution for longest Palindrome substring problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, dynamic-programming, palindrome

input:

```
babad
abbd
```

output:

```
ad
bb
```

expected:

```
bab
bb
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        int maxlength=1;
        bool ispalindromic[1000][1000]={false};
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            ispalindromic[i][i]=1;
                
        for(int l=2;l<s.length();l++){
            for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1; i++){
                int j=i+l-1;
                if(l==2&&s[i]==s[j]){
                    ispalindromic[i][j]=1;
                    maxlength=max(maxlength,j-i+1);
                    continue;}
                if(ispalindromic[i+1][j-1]&&s[i]==s[j]){
                    ispalindromic[i][j]=1;
                    maxlength=max(maxlength,j-i+1);
                }
            }}
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        int j=i+maxlength-1;
            if(ispalindromic[i][j]){
                return s.substr(i,j);
            }
        }
        return s.substr(0,1);
    }
};
```

I created `ispalindromic[1000][1000]` first and made sure that every alphabet itself is palindromic. Then I check palindromic from the length of 2 and so on. Whenever `ispalindromic` becomes true, the code updates `maxlength` so that in the end the code can simply use `maxlength` to print longest palindromic.

Comment: This is imho a bit off topic here, and should probably be asked on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). And if you expect someone to look at your code to search for a logical errors, it should be reasonably formatted.

Comment: it looks like you never consider that whole string might be a palindrome, try testing with `rotor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with this code.

1. Indices of your for loops
   When you consider the length `l` of a possible substring, your `l` should go between 2 to `s.length()`, so the outer for loop should be:

   `for(int l=2;l<=s.length();l++){` You see I changed `l < s.length()` to `l <= s.length()`
2. Then your `i` index of inner loop should go from `0` to `s.length()-l` it cannot go further than that when you consider a string of length `l`. It needs to be modified as :

   `for(int i=0;i<s.length()-l+1; i++){`
3. Then `if` condition for `l=2` should be modified as :

   ```
             if(l==2){
                if ( s[i] == s[j] ) {
                 ispalindromic[i][j]=1;
                  maxlength=max(maxlength,j-i+1);
                }

                continue;
            }
   ```

   You need to move `s[i] == s[j]` inside the `if` because irrespective of `s[i] == s[j]` you need to continue as per your code.
4. You need to print the substr that spans a length of `maxlength` so your return statement should be : `return s.substr(i,maxlength);`

With those corrections, the code is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        int maxlength = 1;
        bool ispalindromic[1000][1000] = {false};

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            ispalindromic[i][i] = 1;
        }

        for (int l = 2; l <= s.length(); l++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - l + 1; i++) {
                int j = i + l - 1;

                if (l == 2) {
                    if ( s[i] == s[j] ) {
                        ispalindromic[i][j] = 1;
                        maxlength = max(maxlength, j - i + 1);
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                if (ispalindromic[i + 1][j - 1] && s[i] == s[j]) {
                    ispalindromic[i][j] = 1;
                    maxlength = max(maxlength, j - i + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int j = i + maxlength - 1;

            if (ispalindromic[i][j]) {
                return s.substr(i, maxlength);
            }
        }

        return s.substr(0, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: 3. but the next ```if ```will be false 4. why can't be j?

Comment: @JacksonSteel - 3. for `l = 2`, `j = i + 1` right? lets say `s[i] != s[j] `then the `if ( l == 2 && s[i] == s[j] )` fails and it comes to the next if there `ispalindromic[i+1][i+1-1] = ispalindromic[i+1][i] ` will be checked, is that what you really want ? 4. In c++ `substr` is the substring is the portion of the object that starts at character position pos and spans len characters (or until the end of the string, whichever comes first). If you pass `j` it will span `j` characters from `i` which is not what you want. You want to span `maxlength` chracters from `i`.

Comment: 3. and ```spalindromic[i+1][i+1-1] = ispalindromic[i+1][i]``` is false, right?

Comment: @JacksonSteel, it could be true if s[i] == s[i+1] but thats not the direction you want to go, because you are building table step by step for each length, you will consider cases where i <= j.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the problems that you're facing. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63267195/6553328) is correct, addresses your problems.

Apart from that, this'll also get through and is similarly a dynamic programming method, just like yours:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

const static struct Solution {
    using SizeType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    static std::string longestPalindrome(const std::string s) {
        const SizeType slen = std::size(s);

        if (slen < 2) {
            return s;
        }

        SizeType maxlen = 0;
        SizeType head = 0;
        SizeType curr = 0;

        while (curr < slen) {
            SizeType left = curr;
            SizeType right = curr;

            while (right < slen - 1 and s[right] == s[-~right]) {
                ++right;
            }

            curr = -~right;

            while (right < slen - 1 and left > 0 and s[-~right] == s[left - 1]) {
                ++right;
                --left;
            }

            SizeType templen = -~right - left;

            if (templen > maxlen) {
                head = left;
                maxlen = templen;
            }
        }

        return s.substr(head, maxlen);
    }
};


// -~x is simply x + 1;
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/discuss/) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Please explain what was wrong with the original code and how you fixed it. Just posting new code is not as informative.

Comment: It seems like your code is a totally different algorithm, it doesn't actually address the problems in the original code.